# Wireless both way sync of photos on iPhone

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, wifi, photos, graphics

iTunes allows you to "sync" pictures however this only copies files from Mac to iPhone, forcing me to do it manually over the USB cable if I want to copy my photos from iPhone to my Mac.

I'm running Jailbroken iOS 6.1.1 on my iPhone so I tried to automate this task by running SSH server on the device and by creating auto-sync task on my mac using GoodSync. This seem to work however I don't find it to be a reliable solution to my problem because sometimes it still forces me to initialise the sync and because SSH server can be running only when iPhone's screen is on, breaking the connection during sync.

So I was wondering if there is another way to wirelessly sync pictures between my Mac and iPhone without any interaction from me.

Comment: Photostream via iCloud?

Comment: I don't want to use Photostream for couple reasons:

1. iPhoto needs to be installed on Mac, which is a waste of space considering that it is 1GB and I have an SSD

2. Uploading photos to the cloud just to sync them with my computer on LAN is an overkill + its slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, DropBox is the way to go.

Not only will you never lose a photo to Photostream's delete, but Camera Uploads silently uploads all your iDevice photos—and automatically syncs them to your desktop, if you wish. ("Selective Syncing.") Also of course makes them shareable as well.

Comment: I have just tried using Dropbox for that and it seems to be ok so far. Is there any way to have photos deleted on the iPhone when I remove any of them on my laptop?

Comment: Sure. Simplest would be to remove them by hand, delete from Camera Roll and Photostream on phone. There are ways to clear the whole Photostream; warning: may cause headaches.

Comment: It seems that Photostream, at least for now, is the only way to ultimately sync photos both ways. Thanks for suggestion about Dropbox.

I pointed iTunes photo library to Dropbox folder on my laptop and managed to achieve a quite fast and reliable both way sync.